# My setstate method is called multiple times which is causing a problem in deleting items in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-native-flatlist

I'm new to React Native and working on a small project. I'm calling a network call and rendering items in a FlatList. Im getting issue when deleting items because setRenderData method is called continously. How do i prevent this from happening? how do i call it only once? I have tried some solutions but i can't understand where the issue is. Please help me.

```
export default function TextExtractor() {
  const [pickerResponse, setPickerResponse] = useState(null);
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);
  var [renderData, setRenderData] = useState([]);
const onRemove = id => e => {
   setRenderData(renderData.filter(renderData => renderData.Id !== id))
   };
   const Item = ({ title,id }) => (
     <View style={styles.item}>
       <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
    <TouchableOpacity  onPress={onRemove(id)}>
       <Image
style={{width:30,height:30}}
            source={require('../assets/delete.png')}
          />
          </TouchableOpacity>
     </View>
   );

  useEffect(() => {
   
    return () => {
      setRenderData({});
    };
}, []);

  const onImageLibraryPress = useCallback(() => {
  
    const options = {
      selectionLimit: 1,
      mediaType: 'photo',
      includeBase64: false,
    };
    ImagePicker.launchImageLibrary(options, setPickerResponse);
  }, []);

  const onCameraPress = useCallback(() => {
    const options = {
      saveToPhotos: true,
      mediaType: 'photo',
      includeBase64: false,
      maxWidth: 500,
      maxHeight: 500,
      quality: 0.5,
    };
    ImagePicker.launchCamera(options, setPickerResponse);
  }, []);

  const handleUploadPhoto = () => {
    setVisible(false);
  
     const data = new FormData();
   

      data.append("file_uploaded", {
         name: pickerResponse.assets[0].fileName,
         type: pickerResponse.assets[0].type,
         uri:
           Platform.OS === "android"
             ? pickerResponse.assets[0].uri
             : pickerResponse.assets[0].uri.replace("file://", "")
       }); 
 
       var url ='https://bacodetextextract.com/upload/image/';
   
       axios.post(url, data, {headers: {
         "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
         Accept: "application/json"
        
       }})
       .then((res) => {
    
        setRenderData(res.data);
     

         console.log(‘RESULT: ',renderData);

 
       })
       .catch((err) => {
         console.log('error', err);
       })
   };

  const uri = pickerResponse?.assets && pickerResponse.assets[0].uri;

  if(uri!==undefined){
 

  handleUploadPhoto();
  }

  const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
    <Item title={item.Text}
    id = {item.Id}
    />
  );
  return (
    <View style={styles.screen}>
 
      <ImagePickerAvatar uri={uri} onPress={() => setVisible(true)} />

      <FlatList style={styles.usernameText}
        data={renderData}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        keyExtractor={item => item.Id}
      />
     
      <ImagePickerModal
        isVisible={visible}
        onClose={() => setVisible(false)}
        onImageLibraryPress={onImageLibraryPress}
        onCameraPress={onCameraPress}
      />


    </View>
  );
}

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

T.J.Crowder solved your problem with the repeated re-rendering. The second problem is this part of your code:

```js
const onRemove = id => e => {
   setRenderData(renderData.filter(renderData => renderData.Id !== id))
   };
```

I don't think `id => e=> {}` is a valid syntax, it should be like this:

```js
const onRemove = (id) => {
   setRenderData(renderData.filter(renderData => renderData.Id !== id))
   };
```

I found another reason why you keep calling `setRenderData`. You have `setRenderData` in this function :

```js
onst handleUploadPhoto = () => {
  setVisible(false);

  const data = new FormData();
  

  data.append("file_uploaded", {
    name: pickerResponse.assets[0].fileName,
    type: pickerResponse.assets[0].type,
    uri:
      Platform.OS === "android"
        ? pickerResponse.assets[0].uri
        : pickerResponse.assets[0].uri.replace("file://", "")
  }); 

  var url ='https://bacodetextextract.com/upload/image/';

  axios.post(url, data, {headers: {
    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
    Accept: "application/json"
  
  }})
  .then((res) => {

  setRenderData(res.data);


    console.log(‘RESULT: ',renderData);


  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log('error', err);
  })
};
```

and everytime you re-render it call this line again. If `uri` is not `undefined` then it will call `handleUploadPhoto` again and again.

```js
const uri = pickerResponse?.assets && pickerResponse.assets[0].uri;

if(uri!==undefined){
  handleUploadPhoto();
}
```

My suggestion is to make it like this:

```js
useEffect(()=>{
  const uri = pickerResponse?.assets && pickerResponse.assets[0].uri;

  if(uri!==undefined){
    handleUploadPhoto();
  }
},[pickerResponse])
```

In the code above we put the codes that causing the problem in a `useEffect` so that it will only be called whenever `pickerResponse` change instead of calling them every render

Comment: Thanks. Delete function is called now but this line setRenderData(res.data) is still called multiple times, therefore even after deleting, list is populating with the original list.

Comment: I just add a new answer to my post, check it out

Comment: Ok then how or where do I call handleUploadPhoto() method?

Comment: I just edited it again, see the last part for my suggestion

Answer (score 0):

It's not a problem that `setRenderData` is called repeatedly, but there are two problems in your code:

1. `onPress={onRemove(id)}` should be `onPress={() => onRemove(id)}`. You need to provide a function as the `onPress` property, not the *result* of calling a function.
2. Whenever you're setting new state based on existing state, it's best practice (and often *necessary* practice) to use the callback version of the function so that you're operating on up-to-date state. You pass in a *function* that receives the up-to-date state:

   ```
   setRenderData(renderData => renderData.filter(
       renderData => renderData.Id !== id
   ));
   ```

---

Side note: Part of your code is expecting `renderData` to be an array, but another part of your code is doing `setRenderData({})`, which will make it a non-array object. It happens that part of the cleanup callback of a `useEffect` with no dependencies so that object isn't going to be used by the component (because that cleanup is only done when the component is unmounted), but it's still not best practice. (There's also no need to do that, all state is released when the component is unmounted.)

Comment: Thanks for replying. I made both the changes in my code. After I made the first change, delete is not working, i mean that function is not calling when i checked the logs.
<TouchableOpacity  onPress={()=>onRemove(id)}>
       <Image

            style={{width:30,height:30}}
            source={require('../assets/delete.png')}
          />
          </TouchableOpacity>

Comment: @spykeburn - Then something *else* is going on. `onPress={() => onRemove(id)}` is correct.

Comment: is my onRemove function wrongly written? coz it was working with previous line which was onPress{onRemove(id)}